# Magento: Bundle options container "container2" empty

Tags: magento, bundle, frontend

I'm Using Magento 1.5.1.0 and I have programmatically added bundle products (directly into the database with a custom built PHP script).

For most bundle products, the bundle options show fine on the frontend, but for some products, the code:

```
$this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true)
```

Returns an empty string.

I have no idea how to troubleshoot this and the bundle options do show up in Magento Admin Panel when I go to the product though Manage Products.

Any ideas as to what I could try to check why the bundle options are not being displayed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out this error occurred because the attribute set that these bundle products belong to did no longer have the "options_container" attribute, because it did no longer have the "design" attribute group assigned to it.
I fixed that and now everything is okay again.

Just answered my own question because maybe someone would run into this problem and I know it caused me headaches to figure it out.

Comment: I had a similar problem (`container2` always empty), changing the value of `options_container` worked. Thanks!